# How to disable apache control panel in server

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have an eclipse application running on Apache Tomcat server. I've got a requirement to disable Apache control panel in server. Please help hoe this can be done. I've tried doing this with the link https://ipaddress:9999/ by seeing on one site. Buy this doesn't help.

Comment: which control panel? The manager app?

Comment: Yes. Its the manager app. Please suggest on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your tomcat directory, go into `webapps` and move `manager` out of `webapps`. Don't copy it, move it. It ca be in your tomcat directory, but no longer under `webapps`.

Then restart tomcat.